# Search box is not working when placed on the background image using bootstrap?

Tags: html

MY search box is not responsive when I am placing it in the background image using bootstrap.

html:

```
         <div class="wrapper">
         <div class="page-header section-dark" style="background-image:  
          url('assets/img/5514.jpg'); 
          filter: brightness(200%)">
          <form class="form-inline ml-auto w-50">
            <input class="form-control" type="search" placeholder="Topic or Keyword" aria- 
       label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-md my-2 my-sm-0 ml-3" 
         type="submit">Search</button>
          </form>
          </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you set a `div` to a class of `wrapper`, it sets `pointer-events` to `none`. Which means clicking the text box won't work.

```
  <div class="page-header section-dark" style="background-image:  
          url('assets/img/5514.jpg'); 
          filter: brightness(200%)">
    <form class="form-inline ml-auto w-50">
      <input class="form-control" type="search" placeholder="Topic or Keyword" aria- label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-md my-2 my-sm-0 ml-3" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: Try to remove the wrapper class, I don't think that's needed.

Comment: alignment is disturbed when wrapper div is removed